# How to integrate a bluetooth thermal printer with my Flutte app

Tags: flutter, dart, printing, thermal-printer

How to integrate a bluetooth thermal printer with my Flutte app so that i can directy print pdf instead of saving and opening with other printing app like thermer?
Actually I am working on a Toll Ticket Printing app. I want to print the pdf toll ticket.

I tried many famous flutter packages but getting errors e.g. channel errors etc

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.